# Parsing Soap Message

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, xml-parsing

I recently started to work with SOAP.
Right now I am trying to parse SOAP message in C#.
Message is as it follows:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <ns1:getBuildingsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://someserver.net/~username/lab/servis?ws=1">
    <return SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:Map[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
    <item>
      <key xsi:type="xsd:string">id</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key xsi:type="xsd:string">code</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">345-GESG</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key xsi:type="xsd:string">name</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Building 1</value>
    </item>
  </item>
  <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
    <item>
      <key xsi:type="xsd:string">id</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">7590913</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key xsi:type="xsd:string">code</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">353-gr</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key xsi:type="xsd:string">name</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Building 2</value>
    </item>
  </item>
</return>
```

I want to extract values of keys **id**,**code** and **name**.
I tried doing something like this:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(client.Invoke("getBuildings").ToString());
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("i", "item");
XmlNodeList xNodelst = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("item", nsmgr);
Console.WriteLine(xNodelst.Count); 
foreach (XmlNode xn in xNodelst)
{
   Console.WriteLine(xn.Value);
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to act with tags that have no namespace...
This line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine(xNodelst.Count);
```

always prints 0, but I want it to print 2, since I have 2 elements in array (ns2:Map[2]).
Meaning, I want to loop through all of these elements:

```
<item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.LoadXml(client.Invoke("getBuildings").ToString());    
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);    
    XmlNodeList nodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("//item[@xsi:type='ns2:Map']",nsmgr);
    var nodeCount=nodes.Count;
```

try this, this might help you.

Comment: It is working after I edited it:
`XmlNodeList nodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("//item[@xsi:type='ns2:Map']",nsmgr);`
`Console.WriteLine(nodes.Count); //prints 2`

Comment: One more question: how to extract **key** and **value** fields from each item?